# Selenium Java Can't Select AngularJS Element

Tags: java, angular, selenium, xpath

I have researched and tried several different ways of identifying this element for an assertion test. Xpath didn't work, ng-model didn't work. Any ideas?

```
    <input type="text" ng-class="{'ng-dirty': !merchant.name}" ng-
    model="merchant.name" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty 
    ng-valid-required ng-touched" style="">
```

Code I have so far:

```
@Test
public static void merchant_name() {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement merchant_name = driver.findElement(
                By.xpath("input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-required ng-touched']")
            );
    Assert.assertEquals(merchant_name.getAttribute("value"), "Regression Testing");
}
```

Comment: Can you extend your question with  those different ways you have tried?

Comment: No problem. Here is my attempt at DebanjanB's suggestion:

Comment: @Test
public static void merchant_name() { driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   
WebElement merchant_name = driver.findElement(By.xpath("input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-required ng-touched']"));
Assert.assertEquals(merchant_name.getAttribute("value"), "Regression Testing");
 }

Comment: Are there any exceptions? Afai there should be NPE when youy invoke getAttribute of the xpath does not return anything?.

Comment: Got it. See below. Tried a different approach with xPath. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to use the following `xpath` using the `class` attribute:

```
//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-required ng-touched']
```

Another strategy may be to use both the `class` and `type` attribute:

```
//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-required ng-touched' and @type='text']
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick.

```
    @Test
    public static void merchant_name() {
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);   
    WebElement merchant_name = 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/ng-
    view/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ng-form/div[3]/div/input"));
    Assert.assertEquals(merchant_name.getAttribute("value"), "Regression 
    Testing");
    }
```